# Jmeter JavaSampler - Can we pass instance of WebDriver which was already created in Jmeter WDS?

Tags: java, jmeter

I have created a Jar file of Junit in Java, can we pass instance of WebDriver 
to one of the methods in Junit test, because I want to use same instance of IE Driver in both Jnuit and WDS script of Jmeter.

PS: We have used Junit to automate some areas which we are not able to do in Jmeter WDS.

Comment: Can you show the code and what you failed to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like:

1. In the [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/):

   ```
   WDS.vars.putObject("WDS.browser", WDS.browser);
   ```
2. In the [JUnit Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JUnit_Request)

   ```
   WebDriver driver = (WebDriver) JMeterContextService.getContext().getVariables().getObject("WDS.browser");
   ```

However in fact you should be able to do everything you need directly in the WebDriver Sampler.

If you use JavaScript language - check out the following materials:

- [Using Java From Scripts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/prog_guide/javascript.html)
- [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered)

If you use Groovy language - you should be able to use the same code you're going to use in the JUnit Request sampler directly in the WebDriver sampler.